# CSV - SSIS - SQL Server, Character Encoding Problems

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a large set of CSV files which I am transferring to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I am using a SSIS package in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to achieve this.  I currently have around 2 million lines of data so I need SSIS

The problem I have is that while the data in my CSV already has encoding issues I am making them far worse in transit.

For now what I need to do is just maintain the characters so that whatever I see in my CSV appears in my SQL server table. I am particularly interested in 'Benoît' which is fine in my CSV but not in my SQL table where it becomes 'BenoŒt' Please see the list at the bottom of my post.

I am also wondering if once I have imported the data in its current state I can reliably use find and replace to deal with the existing encoding issues from my CSV's

Character encoding is a confusing subject and I am not all sure if a couple of paragraphs can put me on the right track. Please help with a steer (if its possible!) I am sure I need to look at the settings across both SQL server and Visual studio but am not sure what needs a tweaking or where..

"Benoît" in my CSV becomes "BenoŒt" in my SQL table

"AngÃ©lique" in my CSV becomes "AngÇŸ¶¸lique" in my SQL table

"MichÃ¨le" in my CSV becomes "MichÇŸ¶ùle" in my SQL table

"josÃ©e" in my CSV becomes "josÇŸ¶¸e" in my SQL table

"AmÃ©lie" in my CSV becomes "AmÇŸ¶¸lie" in my SQL table

Comment: Don't try to fix a CSV encoding error in the database, it's not the database that's broken. Make sure your CSV files are Unicode-encoded or convert them to Unicode, then import them to SQL Server.  SQL Server supports Unicode with the nvarchar type so if you import Unicode data, so there are no conversion errors. Or, specify the *correct* codepage in your CSV source when importing the data so SQL Server can correctly map characters to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your `CSV` files are in the `Unicode` encoding (try to open `CSV` file in the Notepad-> Save As -> and check `Encoding` in the bottom). If they are not - save them in `Unicode`

[image]

And make sure that in the `Flat File Source` properties inside SSIS packege the `Unicode` check box is selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file needs to be in UCS-2 Little Endian encoding.

Please open it in notepad++ to check.